# Two level approval workflow in sharepoint designer 2010

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I want to create an approval workflow that goes like this.

Form filled in -> click submit -> send to first person to approve ->(if not rejected)-> send to second person to approve ->(if not rejected)-> send to last person(no approve).

Does somebody have a workflow in sharepoint designer that does this? Or a tutorial which actually shows the workflow steps in designer?

Comment: You could use a state machine workflow for this, and have a custom approval task that changes additional customized "Approval Status" columns.  See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36969/how-to-create-a-customized-yet-still-semi-basic-state-machine-workflow-with-sh/36970#36970 for a general idea of how to create a state machine workflow in SPD2k10

Answer (score 3):

Laura Rogers has some great tutorials on approval workflows using OOTB technologies, such as InfoPath and SharePoint Designer.  Here are some posts / demos you might find helpful:

- Workflow: next approver is my VP (similar to your multi-approver scenario) http://sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=88
- Creating a workflow initiation form for approvals: http://sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=176

Stephen Howard also has an excellent set of approval workflow tutorials on Office.com:

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/watch-this-design-a-document-review-workflow-solution-HA010256417.aspx

The workflow gets slightly tricky if the "approvers" change every time the workflow runs, but it can be done. It is easy if the approvers are the same every time.

Answer (score 0):

The process that you are describing is exactly how the "Approval Process" action in SharePoint Designer 2010 works right out of the box.

All you'd need to do is create a workflow that uses Initiation Form Parameters that will serve as the fields that you want users to fill in on your form.

The sending to one person for approval and if not rejected sending to the next, is called "serial" processing and that is the default way that the approval action sends its approval tasks out.

Answer (score -1):

Based on [this article](http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2009/10/the-new-approval-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflows) you can have serial or parallel recipients and have multiple assignment stages.

Pay more attention on **Change the behaviour of a single task** and **Assigned to Users**