# Approval Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

When a user uploads a document, it emails their manager, the manager goes in and reviews the document and approves it and the workflow is closed out. (This part works).

What I would like is for when a user uploads a document, it emails their manager, the manager approves the document and then the process enters into the acceptance phase. the user then has to accept the changes and then the task process is closed out. Until that is done, the process would be pending. How would I nest this second task in and tie the two task processes together? Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two level approval workflow in sharepoint designer 2010](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37183/two-level-approval-workflow-in-sharepoint-designer-2010)

Comment: Confirm - seems to be a special case of the above question (the second level approver coincides with the original uploader)